# Deploying a docker image from gitlab container registry to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a basic node app that I've wrapped in a Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

I push that to Gitlab's container registry. I'm trying to deploy it from there to AWS, but running into problems on the ECS side. In ECS I have:

- a cluster (frontend)
- a service (frontend)

both of which are configured in terraform

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "frontend" {
  name = "frontend"

  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "frontend" {
  name    = "frontend"
  cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.frontend.id

  deployment_controller {
    type = "EXTERNAL"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "WebAppFrontend"
  }
}
```

The web app is in a different repository from the terraform infrastructure. In my .gitlab-ci.yml I'm trying to register a new task definition for the web app I'm trying to register a new task definition with a json file.

I want when there's been changes to the web app I was to perform a rolling update so both the new version and old version are running, but I can't get one version deployed to ecs. My .gitlab-ci.yml is

```
deploy_ecs:
  stage: deploy_ecs
  script:
    - aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://task_definition.json
```

task_definition.json is:

```
{
    "family": "frontend",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "frontend",
        "image": "registry.gitlab.com/myproject/application/myimage:latest",
        "memory": 300,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "hostPort": 80
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "Frontend",
                "value": "dev"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Attempting to create a service from the console I get this error

```
The selected task definition is not compatible with the selected compute strategy.
```

Manually on the ec2 instance infrastructure for the ecs cluster I can run

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 myimage
```

which does run the app. Am I able to:

1. Deploy the task definition file as above and run the service in my cluster
2. Deploy in a way so that there will be both versions in a rolling update to avoid any downtime
3. Do both of the above from my .gitlab-ci.yml

The ec2 instance is confirmed to be running the ecs-agent and I can see the container instance showing correctly so I know ecs is running.

Comment: That error typically means you have configured a task definition for Fargate, but are trying to deploy it to EC2, or vice versa.

Comment: I've added requiresCompatibilities": [ "EC2" ] to my task_definition.json but getting the same error, not sure what it is

Answer (score 0):

I used console and the service was created successfully.

```
{
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "family": "frontend",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "frontend",
        "image": "registry.gitlab.com/myproject/application/myimage:latest",
        "memory": 300,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "hostPort": 80
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "Frontend",
                "value": "dev"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

The task eventually failed with access denied but the rest everything worked. Plus you need to add the " ecsTaskExecutionRole" for the task to function.